# Question about using multiple graphic cards to rendering

Tags: rendering, hardware

I have some questions about multiple graphic card . Now I am using GTX1060 6G .I want to add another graphic card to speed up my rendering process(For example: GTX 1060 6G x2 or GTX 1060 6g+GTX 10series).

Can I just install another graphic card without doing anything(SLI) ? leave them as two single cards inside one computer.Does it matter that my motherboard dose not support SLI but it has

2 x PCIe 3.0 x 16 SafeSlots (CPU)

1 x PCIe 2.0 x 16 slot (PCH)

1 x PCIe 2.0 x 1 slots (PCH)

(Asus B350 F with 550w power)

Which should I plugin?Another PCIe 3.0 x 16 SafeSlots?

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Do not use SLI when using blender.

Answer (score 1):

Nvidia has disabled SLI for the 1060.

Blender can make use of multiple gpus that are plugged in but not connected to each other (via corrsfire or SLI or whatever there is).

But there are a few downsides: 
 - the memory of the cards don't add up. as both cards need to store the
   scene information in the memory, the card with less memory is the
   bottleneck
 - you'll have a "dead" card in your setup almost all the time (except when you are actually rendering)

Comment: Thanks!! I got it .But if I need to rendering an animation two 1060 is faster than single 1080 right?According to "GPU benchmarks | BlenchMark" . Just the downsides is I will have a dead card expect when I was rendering